# Animating button to present a spinner in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibutton, uianimation

So I want to make a button **animate on press to go to a circle**, and then be able to send the button **back to its original state**. This is my current animation, and as you can see I'm halfway there.

[image: GIF showing how the animation is currently working]

As you also can see I'm having multiple issues here. First of all, when I set my new constraints the X constraint doesn't place the circle in the middle of the parent view. And then my initial thought was that when i call the reset function, that I would also pass the original constraints of the view, but that just isn't working.

My idea is that when i'm using it i'll put a UIView and then have the button inside that view, so I can manipulate the constraints of it. This would also be the case if i'm putting a button in a UIStackView.

#### Here's my code, any input would be awesome

```
extension UIButton {

func animateWhileAwaitingResponse(showLoading: Bool, originalConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]) {

    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    let constraints = [
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.superview, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 45),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 45),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.superview, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 4),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.superview, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: spinner, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: spinner, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: spinner, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 45),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: spinner, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 45)
    ]

    if showLoading {

        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.constraints)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        spinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(spinner)
        self.superview?.addConstraints(constraints)
        spinner.color = .white
        spinner.startAnimating()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.setTitleColor(.clear, for: .normal)
            self.layer.cornerRadius = 22.5
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.constraints)
            self.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            self.superview?.addConstraints(originalConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(originalConstraints)
            self.layer.cornerRadius = 0

            for subview in self.subviews where subview is UIActivityIndicatorView {
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show your button constraints?

Comment: I have tried multiple different constraints. Top, bottom, left, right. But also width, height and center

Comment: I have tried your code, when animation done and button become circle, it's position in center, but, vertical constraints not match and it's move up. then when second animation happens, button become square instead of original position and size.

Comment: Yeah. But I'm not sure how to solve it...

Comment: Give me few minute, I think I'm able to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your button extension code as follow, which is adding and removing constraints with animation.

```
extension UIButton {

    func animateWhileAwaitingResponse(showLoading: Bool, originalConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]) {

        let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        spinner.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        // Constraints which will add in supper view
        let constraints = [
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.superview, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.superview, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),

            NSLayoutConstraint(item: spinner, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: spinner, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: spinner, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 45),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: spinner, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 45)
        ]

        // Constrains which will add in button
        let selfCostraints = [
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 45),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 45),
        ]

        // Keeping this outside of condition due to adding constrains programatically.
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        spinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        if showLoading {

            // Remove width constrains of button from superview
            // Identifier given in storyboard constrains
            self.superview?.constraints.forEach({ (constraint) in
                if constraint.identifier == "buttonWidth" {
                    constraint.isActive = false
                }
            })

            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.constraints)

            self.addSubview(spinner)
            self.superview?.addConstraints(constraints)
            self.addConstraints(selfCostraints)
            spinner.color = .white
            spinner.startAnimating()
            spinner.alpha = 0

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.setTitleColor(.clear, for: .normal)
                self.layer.cornerRadius = 22.5
                spinner.alpha = 1
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)

        } else {


            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

                for subview in self.subviews where subview is UIActivityIndicatorView {
                    subview.removeFromSuperview()
                }

                self.removeConstraints(selfCostraints)
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.constraints)
                self.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
                self.superview?.addConstraints(originalConstraints)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate(originalConstraints)
                self.layer.cornerRadius = 0

                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I have added following constrains to button:

[image: Button Constrains]

Also, added identifier of button's width constraint to remove from super which will add runtime from original constrains.

[image: Width Constrains]

Then I have change width of button programatically by taking outlet of width constrains:

```
@IBOutlet weak var const_btnAnimation_width : NSLayoutConstraint!
```

inside `viewDidLoad` method

```
self.const_btnAnimation_width.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40
```

where 40 is sum of leading and trailing space.

on button click

```
@IBAction func btnAnimationPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

    if sender.isSelected {
        self.btnAnimation.animateWhileAwaitingResponse(showLoading: true, originalConstraints: sender.constraints)
    } else {
        self.btnAnimation.animateWhileAwaitingResponse(showLoading: false, originalConstraints: self.btnAnimationConstraints)
    }
}
```

`btnAnimationConstraints` is array of `NSLayoutConstraint` as follow:

```
var btnAnimationConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
```

So I just assign all constrains of button inside `viewDidAppear` method as follow:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.btnAnimationConstraints = self.btnAnimation.constraints
}
```

I hope this will help you.

**Output:**

[image: Button Animation]

Comment: Thanks man, I tried making it without adding any constraints as outlets - but this is a great solution.

Comment: You can access constrains runtime without outlet by adding identifier and update it.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you set `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` in the first animation but you didn't set it back to `true` in your second animation.

That may be a source of the problem: you need to set `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` during your second animation.

It will probably be less confusing if you turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` in Interface Builder (or wherever you create the button initially), and do all your layout with normal constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I am updating code to set dynamic button height and manage the circle according to button parent height. You can use

> button.frame.height

to make a circle.

```
extension UIButton {

func animateWhileAwaitingResponse(showLoading: Bool, originalConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]) {

    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    spinner.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    // Constraints which will add in supper view
    let constraints = [
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.superview, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.superview, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: spinner, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: spinner, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: spinner, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: self.frame.height),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: spinner, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: self.frame.height)
    ]

    // Constrains which will add in button
    let selfCostraints = [
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: self.frame.height),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: self.frame.height),
    ]

    // Keeping this outside of condition due to adding constrains programatically.
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    spinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    if showLoading {

        // Remove width constrains of button from superview
        // Identifier given in storyboard constrains
        self.superview?.constraints.forEach({ (constraint) in
            if constraint.identifier == "buttonWidth" {
                constraint.isActive = false
            }
        })

        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.constraints)

        self.addSubview(spinner)
        self.superview?.addConstraints(constraints)
        self.addConstraints(selfCostraints)
        spinner.color = .white
        spinner.startAnimating()
        spinner.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.setTitleColor(.clear, for: .normal)
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
            spinner.alpha = 1
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)

    } else {


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

            for subview in self.subviews where subview is UIActivityIndicatorView {
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
            }

            self.removeConstraints(selfCostraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.constraints)
            self.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            self.superview?.addConstraints(originalConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(originalConstraints)
            self.layer.cornerRadius = 0

            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So I did some changes and it works perfect for me. And I set base constraints for button in interface builder.

```
// StartAnimation    
self.payButton.startAnimating(originalConstraints: sender.constraints)
// StopAnimation    
self.payButton.startAnimating(false, originalConstraints: sender.constraints)    
    
func startAnimating(_ showLoading: Bool = true, originalConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]) {
                lazy var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
                    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
                    activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    activityIndicator.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                    activityIndicator.color = .white
                    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
                    activityIndicator.alpha = 0
                    return activityIndicator
                }()
        
                let spinnerConst = [
                    activityIndicator.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
                    activityIndicator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
                    activityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor)
                ]
        
                let buttonConst = [
                    self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
                    self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0)
                ]
        
                if showLoading {
                    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(originalConstraints)
        
                    self.addSubview(activityIndicator)
                    self.superview?.addConstraints(buttonConst)
                    self.addConstraints(buttonConst)
                    self.addConstraints(spinnerConst)
        
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                        self.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
                        activityIndicator.alpha = 1
                        self.titleLabel?.alpha = 0
                        self.layoutIfNeeded()
                    }, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        
                        for subview in self.subviews where subview is UIActivityIndicatorView {
                            subview.removeFromSuperview()
                        }
                        self.removeConstraints(spinnerConst)
                        self.removeConstraints(buttonConst)
                        self.superview?.removeConstraints(buttonConst)
                        self.superview?.addConstraints(originalConstraints)
                        self.addConstraints(originalConstraints)
                        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(originalConstraints)
                        self.titleLabel?.alpha = 1
                        self.layer.cornerRadius = 6
                        self.layoutIfNeeded()
                    }, completion: nil)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**If someone looking for Swift UI code [SWIFT 5].**

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
struct ButtonContentView: View {
    @State private var isButtonPressed = false
    @State private var isLoading = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    isButtonPressed.toggle()
                    isLoading.toggle()
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    withAnimation {
                        isButtonPressed.toggle()
                        isLoading.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }) {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                    Text(isButtonPressed ? "" : "Press Me")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: isButtonPressed ? 60 : 200, height: isButtonPressed ? 60 : 50)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .clipShape(isButtonPressed ? RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50) : RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                }
                
            }
            
            if isLoading {
                CircularProgressView()
                    .opacity(isButtonPressed ? 1 : 0)
                    .scaleEffect(isButtonPressed ? 1 : 0)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CircularProgressView: View {
    @State private var rotation = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .trim(from: 0.08, to: 1.0)
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 4, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotation))
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)
                        .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                            rotation = 360.0
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}

struct ButtonContentView_previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ButtonContentView()
    }
}
```